# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CI when using HMVC + MY_Controller + Frontend_Controller + Admin_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-2, hmvc

MY_Controller.php (application/core) :

```
<?php 
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $data = array();
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['errors'] = array();
        $this->data['my_site_name'] = config_item('site_name');

    }
}
```

Frontend_Controller.php (application/libraries)

```
<?php 
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
}
```

pages.php (application/controllers)

```
 class Pages extends Frontend_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->model('app_model');

        }

        public function index()
        {

            $this->view_data['main_content'] = 'frontpage';
            $this->load->view('template', $this->view_data);
            }       
  }
```

pages is set as default route in routes and if I try to load a HMVC module called testmodule like `http://localhost/testmodule` it works nice.

But, when I want to echo this module (index method contains just one line

`echo "Welcome from testmodule!";` ) like:

```
<div class="page">

    <?php $this->load->view('includes/block_left') ?>

    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <?php 
                echo modules::run('testmodule');
            ?>
            <?php  $this->load->view('articles_new'); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CI in C:\wamp\www\application\third_party\MX\Base.php on line 57
```

**EDIT:**

If I tried to change

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
```

to

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller
```

I got this error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file:
```

Any idea what is going wrong? ;(

Comment: Do you have a require statement somewhere?

Comment: What's after `Unable to load the requested file:`?